# Populate ComboBox in Excel with values from php.XML nodes and submit request with values to php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, vba, domdocument

I need help with VBA (that I am really not good at).
I have created a php that spits out an XML with the following format:

`-<employees>
    -<employee>...
        -<date>...
        -<login>...</login>
        -<logout>...</logout>
        -</date>
        -<date>...
        -<login>...</login>
        -<logout>...</logout>
        -</date>
         ...
    -</employee>
...
-</employees>`

I need to build an excel sheet with a combo box showing the list of employees from that XML , combo box to select "Date From" and "Date To" and Submit button.
When Submit is pressed, I need to send employee name, date from and date to to php and get result in xml with the same structure as above (it's the same PHP that handles everything)

Request is to be sent to my php documet and result to be parsed in to a preset form cells (result is in the same format as above).

Any assistance will be appreciated. I am null in VBA.

Thanks !